# iis7 Sever reduce waiting time for Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, iis-7

I resently developed Wordpress site. I tested in GT Matrix,Pingdom website speed Test. The domain name(https://www.acmetek.com) Taking more waiting time(2.38sec). Please Give me Solution
How to reduce the Waiting time. 
also I want to know is this Server issue or My coding issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHzx1.png)

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your server is incredibly slow. The only solution is to move your site to any good hosting or even Virtual Private Server (VPS).

Google Pagespeed test considers server as slow if it answers in more than 200ms. Your server answers 10 times longer.